# Reading unstrucutred excel file into hive

Tags: excel, hive

i have excel file with rows and column values mixed up. like column value in rows and few row values will be in column oriented. how to read this kind of file and store into hive.? any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more specific and provide an example with concrete values? Ie what are the source tables in Excel and how do you expect them to look like in Hive?
Then, the community can help you much better

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking,the Excel data imported by Hive should first be converted into a txt format file that can be read by the linux system, and then imported into the hdfs file system, and then imported from the hdfs file into hive with the load command.